# Can't install Xcode 7 beta 5's iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7-beta5

[image]

I have no idea why Components section have nothing.

I removed and reinstalled again, but it didn't work at all. Does any one know how to fix this problem?

When I launched Xcode 7 beta 5 at the first time, I saw iOS simulators on that section, but suddenly those disappeared and never shows up again.

Comment: I have the same exact issue here. No simulators in beta 5, components list was populated when I first opened the view, but then it promptly cleared itself.

Comment: Which OS are you using? I've read that there are some problems with El Capitan

Comment: El Cap latest beta. I thought they fixed the Xcode issues with the last beta?

Comment: What makes you think that you don't have the simulators? Do you have an active build scheme?

Answer (score 1):

I know this will seem simple, but have you tried checking the box name, "check and install updates automatically" and then done the check and install now button? If that doesn't work, do a restart and then repeat the above steps. If it does not work again, then you are going to have to post your install logs.